# Do I need to take action on a 10.04 LTS server to avoid the heartbleed vulnerability?

Tags: 10.04, lts, openssl

From the heartbleed.com website, I see that OpenSSL 0.9.8 is NOT vulnerable, which is the version that is available on 10.04. That should mean that actually having stuck with 10.04 until now has avoided any problems with this issue for my production servers.

Is that correct or am I still missing something and there is action that should be taken on 10.04 servers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The version in 10.04 is too old to have the vulnerability, no action is needed over the heart bleed bug.

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.1 through 1.0.1f (inclusive) are vulnerable

Comment: If you don't exactly know your Ubuntu version and the obvious command `uname -a` is not helpful, try `lsb_release -d -s`.

Comment: +1 If you have 0.9.8 you are fine ; 10.04 is OK unless you've done something interesting.  Use `openssl version` to check.

Answer (score 2):

you can check if your server is affected:

http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/#«yourserver.tld»

Comment: This assumes that the server is currently publicly accessible....